# Stacking <li> Images

Tags: html, css

What am I missing from this to make these image links stack next to each other? Just simple image links with rollover controlled by CSS.

I feel like I'm missing a margin or a padding or something...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
/* Social */

.social-links {
 padding-top: 50px;
 position: relative;
 
 
}

.social-links-list li{
  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
 
}


.social-links-list li, .social-links-list a {
    height: 36px;
    display: block;
 float:left;
}

.twitter{
 float:left;
    width: 36px;
    background: url('deleted for example');
 background-size: 36px 36px;
}

.twitter a:hover {
    background: url('deleted for example');
 background-size: 36px 36px;
}

.facebook {
 float:left;
    width: 36px;
    background: url('deleted for example');
 background-size: 36px 36px;
}

.facebook a:hover {
    background: url('deleted for example');
 background-size: 36px 36px;
}

.youtube {
 float:left;
    width: 36px;
    background: url('deleted for example');
 background-size: 36px 36px;
}

.youtube a:hover {
    background: url('deleted for example');
 background-size: 36px 36px;
}

.linkedin {
 float:left;
    width: 36px;
    background: url('deleted for example');
 background-size: 36px 36px;
}

.linkedin a:hover {
    background: url('deleted for example');
 background-size: 36px 36px;
}

.blogs {
 float:left;
    width: 36px;
    background: url('deleted for example');
 background-size: 36px 36px;
}

.blogs a:hover {
    background: url('deleted for example');
 background-size: 36px 36px;
}

.googleplus {
 float:left;
    width: 36px;
    background: url('deleted for example');
 background-size: 36px 36px;
}

.googleplus a:hover {
    background: url('deleted for example');
 background-size: 36px 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-links">
 <ul class="social-links-list">
  <li class="twitter"><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li class="facebook"><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li class="youtube"><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li class="linkedin"><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li class="blogs"><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li class="googleplus"><a href="#"></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are positioning them on top of each other with `position`

How about `inline-block`

```
.social-links-list li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adzaXa

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the `position: absolute;` on the li.

```
.social-links-list li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
   /* position: absolute;  REMOVE THIS */
    top: 0;
}
.social-links-list {
    display: flex; /* ADD DISPLAY: FLEX; TO THE UL */
}
```

You should also remove all the `float: left;` styles applied to the anchors.

Comment: Ah! Forgot to remove those before I posted. Had them there for testing purposes. Removed the absolute. Worked like a charm. Only now my rollover links aren't working... Any thoughts?

EDIT: Got it. It was the width.